# Which folders I should put in .gitignore file after creating a project with Clion?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, ninja, .git-folder

When I run a program with CLion, I have the below directories and files  generated automatically except Problem Details.txt

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name

---------------------------

d-----         10/1/2022   3:48 PM                .idea
d-----         10/1/2022   3:48 PM                cmake-build-debug
-a----          5/1/2022   1:42 AM            116 CMakeLists.txt
-a----         6/14/2022   4:03 PM           1106 main.cpp
-a----          1/3/2022   2:33 PM            155 Probelem Details.txt
```

I'm not sure which files I should put into the .gitignore file while I'm pushing this local repo to any remote repo.

I tried to push all the files and folders to the remote repo but it showed me few warnings!

Answer (score 2):

CLion creates a `.idea` folder which keeps your project settings and `cmake-build-...` which is where your executables build depending on your build configuration. Those are not needed since in an online repo you'd only want the cmake project and your source code. Adding these in the `.gitignore` is enough.

```
# CLion project files
.idea
cmake-build-*
```